# .NET Assembly Binding Redirection

Tags: c#, .net, binding, .net-assembly

I have given our support engineers a utility written in .NET that references an assembly in our product. Every time a new version of the product comes out I have to recompile the utility and give the new version to the support engineers because of the assembly binding. The utility the support engineers have references the old assembly that was in the previous version of the product. When they run the utility it does not automatically use the new version that is installed on the system. Is it possible to compile the application in such a way that my utility will automatically use any newer version that might be installed?   I've tried setting "Specific version" property to false on the assembly reference in the IDE.

I'm using .NET 4.0 and VS 2010.

I looked at the article here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx

But I don't see how to make the decision at compile time for my application. If it's even possible? I don't want to have to ship them a new config file or change machine settings every time the product is updated.

EDIT: I can resolve the problem by handling the AssemblyResolve event and explicitly loading the DLL from my installation directory. But is there an easier way? Such as a project setting or config file setting to do this automatically?

Comment: You project should be taking the dll from the folder where the build is located.  So when you added the refference to the build you should browse for the build is located.  Then when you compile it will check the version in your project bin folder against the reference build version and if different it will copy new executable to your bin folder.

Comment: jdweng, you misunderstood the question. Yes, I have done that. This is a runtime problem. Utility references DLL in product. DLL in product is updated to a new version. I want the Utility to use the new version, but it is not because it's bound to the DLL in the old version of the product.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at dependency injection and auto registration through assembly or folder scanning. you can achieve this using any of the IOC frameworks like Structuremaps, Autofac or Unity...etc. They all can do this without hard binding to a specific assembly version. I prefer Structuremaps as I am used to it since 2006.

Structuremaps
[structuremap.github.io](http://structuremap.github.io)

Autofac http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/getting-started/

unity https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx